# How do I control the Store View context when programatically creating an Order?

Tags: orders, multistore, sales-order, store-view

I'm working on a module which imports orders from an external system; the code is working and orders are being created, but are appearing under the wrong Store View.

Our installation uses only a single Website, Group, and Store View: "Main Website > Main Website Store > Default Store View", and so I was surprised to see orders being imported under "Admin > Default > Admin", with an Order Number / Increment Id which doesn't align with our other orders.

How do I assign the Store View to an Order which is programatically created?

---

After reviewing and comparing several code samples, would it be as simple as initializing the `sales/quote` with:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
  ->setStoreId(Mage::app('default')->getStore('default')->getId());
```

The current code is simply:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
```

...would the effect of omitting `setStoreId()` be that the quote, order, and invoice are assigned to the "Admin" store view rather than the "Default Store View"?

Answer (score 0):

you can add this at the top of your import script to emulate a store view

```
$storeId = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load('default')->getId();
$appEmulation = \Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);
```

when you are done add this to get back to the initial store

```
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

This way your orders will be created just like being in the frontend in the default store view.